# Using a BufferedInputStream for reading audio from server

Tags: java, inputstream, urlconnection, javax.sound.sampled

I am getting an `AudioInputStream` from a `URLConnection` via `javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream()`. When passing a `URL` unto the getAudioInputStream() function, everything works perfectly. However, to prevent blocking, I am using a `URLConnection` to get the input stream so that I can set a `timeout`. Since `AudioInputStream` requires the stream to be mark supported and resettable, I am wrapping the `URLConnection` input stream in a `BufferedInputStream`.

When using a `BufferedInputStream`, at the end of individual songs in the stream (which is served by `Icecast`), the AudioInputStream.read() method throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception. It doesn't consistently happen with every song, it appears rather randomly.

This is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 15
    at javazoom.jl.decoder.LayerIDecoder$SubbandLayer1Stereo.read_allocation(Unknown Source)
    at javazoom.jl.decoder.LayerIDecoder.readAllocation(Unknown Source)
    at javazoom.jl.decoder.LayerIDecoder.decodeFrame(Unknown Source)
    at javazoom.jl.decoder.Decoder.decodeFrame(Unknown Source)
    at javazoom.spi.mpeg.sampled.convert.DecodedMpegAudioInputStream.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.tritonus.share.TCircularBuffer.read(TCircularBuffer.java:138)
    at org.tritonus.share.sampled.convert.TAsynchronousFilteredAudioInputStream.read(TAsynchronousFilteredAudioInputStream.java:189)
    at [line where the AudioInputStream.read() is located]
```

**I am wondering, what underlying property of the `BufferedInputStream` would cause this inconsistent behaviour?** After all, a `BufferedInputStream` extends an `InputStream` and should behave the same on the outside.

I have tested this without setting `URLConnection` timeouts, and the error persists, however the moment I switch back to passing the `URL` directly into the `getAudioInputStream()` function, it works.

*I am using `Tritonus` and `JLayer`.

**EDIT:** I can't provide all of the code as the class is quite large. Here is the relevant code.

```
URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();
uc.setReadTimeout(30000);
uc.setConnectTimeout(20000);
uc.connect();

AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(uc.getInputStream()));
```

and the read (af is an instance of a custom class which stores the audio info and declares the `AudioInputStream`)

```
//Performs a necessary conversion
AudioInputStream in = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(af.getAudioFormat(), af.getAudioStream());

while(play) {
    try {
        int n = 0;
        if ((n = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) == -1) {
            break;
        }
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // SourceDataLine.write() here...
}
```

*In case you're wondering, I set up the read loop like that for a reason (with an if statement inside of a while loop).

Source Code for library where read_allocation() is located: https://github.com/libgdx/jlayer-gdx/blob/master/src/javazoom/jl/decoder/LayerIDecoder.java

Comment: You don't need to call connect(). It's automatic. Try it with a larger buffer parameter than the default of 8192 when constructing the BufferedInputStream.

Comment: I tested it with an internal buffer size of 16384 (8192*2) and with sizes much larger than the buffer size of `buffer` in the code posted. The exception is still thrown.

Comment: I tried out a few different scenarios, none of them removing the exception. I tried using an internal buffer size of 8192*4, while the `buffer` (as used in the code above) size was 8192. While I would need to do more testing to confirm, it appeared as if with the 8192*4 it took longer (more songs were played) before the exception was thrown. I also tried making the `buffer` size equal to the internal buffer length. No success so far.

Comment: When you say 'internal buffer size' do you mean the optional buffer size parameter when constructing the BufferedInputStream? Because that's what I'm talking about. Your own application buffer size will little if any effect I would have thought.

Comment: Yes. Either way I made the BufferedInputStream buffer size very large without resolving the issue.

Comment: Further testing reveals that it is most likely caused by corrupted audio files. The exception was thrown without a BufferedInputStream, invalidating my question.

Answer (score 2):

BufferedInputStream only lets you mark/reset to the size of the buffer. Try increasing it past the size of the file.

Comment: The size of the file isn't fixed. The "file" is actually an `Icecast` stream playing a playlist.